# What specimen of caterpillar is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Early this morning, I found this beautiful caterpillar specimen crawling over a leaf:

[image]

[image]

This specimen was found today morning (spring season) in Brazil at Porto Alegre City [30°01′59″S 51°13′48″W](https://www.google.com/maps/search/30%C2%B001%E2%80%B259%E2%80%B3S+51%C2%B013%E2%80%B248%E2%80%B3W). With approximately 1 Inch long.

What kind of specimen is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a "**Monkey slug**" caterpillar (***Phobetron spp***) of the family [Limacodidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limacodidae) (or slug moths).

According to these sites ([here](https://netmercadao.com.br/noticias/detalhes/As-15-lagartas-mais-venenosas-do-mundo) and [here](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2016/01/03/monkey-slug-brazil-lagarta-aranha/)), caterpillars of this type are commonly referred to in Portuguese as "Lagarta-Aranha" (or "lesma-macaco") [literally, "spider caterpillar" and "monkey slug" in English].

The most common *Phobetron* species I can find in Brazil is *Phobetron hipparchia*.

- The caterpillar of this species appears to be quite variable (ranging from browns to reds in color) as is made apparent by [here](https://bugguide.net/index.php?q=search&keys=phobetron&search=Search), [here](https://biogeodb.stri.si.edu/biodiversity/species/1771/), and [here](http://caterpillars.unr.edu/brazil/species/Phipparchia.htm)

[image]

<sup>*Phobetron hipparchia*  (Source: [http://caterpillars.unr.edu/](http://caterpillars.unr.edu/brazil/species/Phipparchia.htm))</sup>

Comment: They're quite interesting as adults as well: https://www.flickriver.com/photos/140413390@N06/39589933685/